# Pandas get_dummies for a column of lists where a cell may have no value in that column

Tags: pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a column in a dataframe where all the values are lists (list of one item usually for each row).  So, I would like to use `get_dummies` to one hot encode all the values.  However, there may be a few rows where there is not a value for the column.  I have seen it originally as a nan and then I have replaced that nan with an empty list, but in either case I do not see 0 and 1s for the result for the get_dummies, but rather each generated column is blank (I would expect each generated column to be 0).

How do I get `get_dummies` to work with an empty list?

```
# create column from dict where value will be a list
X['sponsor_list'] = X['bill_id'].map(sponsor_non_plaw_dict)
# line to replace nan in sponsor_list column with empty list
X.loc[X['sponsor_list'].isnull(),['sponsor_list']] =    X.loc[X['sponsor_list'].isnull(),'sponsor_list'].apply(lambda x: [])
# use of get_dummies to encode the sponsor_list column
X = pd.concat([X, pd.get_dummies(X.sponsor_list.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)], axis=1)
```

Example:

```
111th-congress_senate-bill_3695.txt False ['Menendez,_Robert_[D-NJ].txt']
112th-congress_house-bill_3630.txt False []
111th-congress_senate-bill_852.txt False ['Vitter,_David_[R-LA].txt']
114th-congress_senate-bill_2832.txt False
['Isakson,_Johnny_[R-GA].txt']
107th-congress_senate-bill_535.txt False ['Bingaman,_Jeff_[D-NM].txt']
```

I want to one hot encode on the third column.  That particular data item in the 2nd row has no person associated it with them, so I need that row to be encoded with all 0s.  The reason I need the third column to be a list is because I need to do this to a related column as well where I need to have [0,n] values where n can be 5 or 10 or even 20.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data?

Comment: My understanding of get_dummies is as such.  attribute dummy_na is: bool, default False Add a column to indicate NaNs, if False NaNs are ignored.  This would mean that False does what is doing now, True would create a separate column called NaN for this case with value 1.  Thus it is forcing me to have 1 column with a 1 and telling me I cannot have all the columns be 0?

Comment: MultiLabelBinarizer instead?  I am trying to use a function which is not supported for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

```
X['sponsor_list'] = X['bill_id'].map(sponsor_non_plaw_dict)
X.loc[X['sponsor_list'].isnull(),['sponsor_list']] = X.loc[X['sponsor_list'].isnull(),'sponsor_list'].apply(lambda x: [])
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
X = X.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(X.pop('sponsor_list')),
                      columns=mlb.classes_,
                      index=X.index))
```

I used a MultiLabelBinarizer to capture what I was trying to do.  I still replace nan with empty list before applying, but then I fit_transform to create the 0/1 values which can result in no 1's in a row, or many 1's in a row.